# Why are images from a previously visited website rendering transparently over another website?

Tags: google-chrome, web, transparent, overlays

after visiting a website for a long time, and leaving another open during that time, it seems that the layout of the first, appears on the second. It happens mainly when using chrome, but once the issue appears on chrome, it is as if it stays in memory, and happens in firefox too. I read about memory leaks, but I am not sure that this is the issue, and if I am the only one that has it. I mainly see it happening on the website that I am working on which is why it is an issue, but it happens on the black bars of facebook, and another website called jeuxvideo.com . (This is the template my website uses: http://themes.alessioatzeni.com/html/brushed/).

Here is an image showing the issue, where the layout of youtube overlays another website (the transparent grid you can see over the rest of the website):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgJgT.jpg

Is this a bug with chrome? Because I have looked everywhere and it doesn't seem that anyone else has this issue, or maybe it is just my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably [image persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_persistence), where the colours in the monitor get "stuck" temporarily after being on or off for a long time. The fix would be to upgrade the monitor.

You could confirm this by taking a screenshot while the problem is happening. If you don't see it in the screen shot (try moving the screenshot around the monitor when you see the problem, do the affected areas of the screen move too? or are the artefacts stuck in place?) then the problem is with the hardware.